# Are there similarities between log4J and log4Net?

Tags: apache, logging, log4j, log4net

Original question: What is difference between Log4j and Log4Net and in what scenario should these two be used?

Updated question: Ok so one is for the Java language while the other is for C#/.Net language(s).

That stated, are there commonalities that effect both log4j and log4net? Consider, just for example, if a bug was found to effect log4J; is there a risk that something similar could effect log4Net too (or any of the other ports)? I ask as both are developed by Apache and according to their [logging service documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/), it seems log4net is a port of the original log4J, "similar in spirit to the original log4j" as they state. How close is that spirit and is it something that could feasibly effect other loggers?

Comment: "The Apache log4net library is a tool to help the programmer output log statements to a variety of output targets. log4net is a port of the excellent Apache log4j™ framework to the Microsoft® .NET runtime." - this is literally the first line on the [log4net website](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/).

Comment: Thanks for the information

Answer (score 10):

The Apache Logging Services Project creates and maintains open-source logging frameworks to the public. These services can be simply seperated as below;

- Apache `Log4j` : Next-generation Asynchronous Loggers based on the LMAX Disruptor library. (for Java, JSP, ...)
- Apache `log4php`  : Versatile logging framework for `PHP`.
- Apache `log4net`
  : For the `Microsoft .NET` runtime log framework.
- Apache `chainsaw` : A
  GUI based log viewer. `Chainsaw` is a companion application to log4j
  written by members of the log4j development community.
- Apache `log4j 1`
  extras : Jar file full of additional functionality for `log4j 1.2.x`.
- Apache `log4cxx` : Logging framework for `C++` patterned after log4j.

Answer (score 6):

Log4Net is the .NET (C#, Visual Basic,... ) port of Log4j (which is for Java) .

So, very simply, they are not used with the same languages.